# 'User' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a User model

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = None
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^09(\d{9})$',
                                 message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '09111111111'")
    phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=11, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    # cart_number = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  # shomare cart banki
    birth_day = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

in view I want to have a class to get a User and update it

```
class UserRetrieveUpdateView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwner,)
```

when I want to test it with post man I give this error:

AttributeError at /account/1/

'User' object has no attribute 'user'

this is my url:

```
path('<int:pk>/', views.UserRetrieveUpdateView.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use `IsOwner` as `permission_classes`, since that will look for a `.user` attribute. You can implement a custom user model that will only allow to retrieve the logged in user:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsThatUserPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return request.user == obj
```

and then use that `IsThatUserPermission`:

```
class UserRetrieveUpdateView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsThatUserPermission,)
```